# Set scope for accessing javascript objects from processing.js sketch

Tags: javascript, scope, processing.js

You can use variables and functions that are directly or indirectly accessible from the global scope, from within a processing.js sketch. Is there a way to give it a different object as the global scope to look stuff up in?

Comment: Are these functions already in memory when you want to change their scope? If they are, you would have to re-declare them with the scope you wanted, or if just changing `this` is enough, invoke with `call` or `apply`.

Comment: Well, that depends on the answer. Processing.js translates code from a language called Processing into javascript, but because the execution happens in a javascript environment, the Processing program has access to anything accessible from the global javascript scope. However, I was wondering wether there's a setting in processing.js to modify the javascript output, so it looks up variables in a different scope.

Comment: You can't whitelist but you can blacklist with the much hated [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), if their code gets declared/defined within it's code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not being very specific so I'm just going to point you to the article that explains this on processingjs.org: http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html#interface

That explains how to make your sketch use JavaScript functions (don't access raw variables), and how to make JavaScript call your sketch functions (again, don't access raw variables, write a getter function and call that).

Comment: What I was looking for, was how to limit the javascript functions a sketch can call, but I already found a different solution to my problem. Thank you for your help.